# How to hide "unsaved changes" box at the bottom of Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublime-text-3

I accidentally clicked "Show Unsaved Changes" in the Sublime Text 3 context menu, and it created a pull up container at the bottom of the screen showing a diff between the current state of the file and the saved state.

[image]

The trouble is I can't see any way to get rid of it:

- There's no close button in the right hand corner
- The context menu hasn't switched to "Hide Unsaved Changes", it still says "Show Unsaved Changes" and clicking it simply refreshes the panel
- Shrinking it all the way takes it to a minimum height but doesn't make it disappear
- I can't see any option like "Hide Unsaved Changes" in the View menu

How do I hide it? I'm not ready to save the file yet, I just want to remove it from the screen.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Pressing the "Escape" key on your keyboard causes it to disappear.

Or alternatively, bringing up any other box along the bottom replaces it. For example, "Find" replaces it with the Find box, then you can click the close X icon in the Find box.